# Python Socket causes accept to be called too many times

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, http, webserver

I am trying to write a simple multithreaded web server in Python. 
When a new client socket connects with the server socket, I create a new thread to handle the client socket, like so:

```
(clientsock, (ip, port)) = self.sock.accept()
newthread = ClientThread(ip, port, clientsock)
newthread.start()
```

where the ClientThread class has a run method, which in turn calls the following bit of code:

```
    data_string = ''
    bytes = self.socket.recv(2046)
    bytes_str = bytes.decode('UTF-8')
    data_string += bytes_str
```

where self.socket is the clientsock referenced above.

This code works as expected: 1 thread is created when the server socket accepts a connection from the client socket, and receives the client socket request.

But if I change the above code in order to loop while there is more data, such as:

```
    data_string = ''
    bytes = self.socket.recv(2046)
    while len(bytes) > 0:
        bytes_str = bytes.decode('UTF-8')
        data_string += bytes_str
        print 'data received: %s' % (bytes_str)
        bytes = self.socket.recv(2046)
```

Then I have a strange issue. It seems that accept is being called multiple times, thereby creating a new, unnecessary thread each time.

I.E - if I start up a client and try to access a file, I get the following output from the server:

> ```
> We have accepted a connection from (127.0.0.1, 59983)
> New thread started for (127.0.0.1, 59983)
> We have accepted a connection from (127.0.0.1, 59984)
> New thread started for (127.0.0.1, 59984)
> ```

Why is accept being called multiple times if only one client has connected to the server?

**Edit**
Is this expected behavior?